# Share menu item in System menu and ContextMenu with accelerator

Tags: javafx

In my application I want to have the same menu item appear on both the system menu as well as a context menu. For example, the Copy menu item. In the context menu I also like to show the accelerator key (the same as on the system menu).

Here's where the problem occurs: if you set the accelerator on both menus, both menu items get fired. This is, of course, not what I want…

Is there a way to prevent this? My current work-around is to just not show the accelerators for the context menu, but this isn't really what I want either.

So is there any way of having the accelerator show in the menu but not fire?

Sample code with a context menu and system menu.
If you press CMD/CTRL-C it will fire both handlers :-(

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test_menu;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Hayo Baan
 */
public class Test_Menu extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Event handler
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = (ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Got event from " + ((MenuItem) event.getSource()).getText());
            event.consume();
        };

        // The system menubar
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.setUseSystemMenuBar(true);

        // Edit menu with Copy item
        Menu editMenu = new Menu("Edit");
        menuBar.getMenus().add(editMenu);
        MenuItem editCopy = new MenuItem("Edit Copy");
        editCopy.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Shortcut+C"));
        editMenu.getItems().add(editCopy);
        editCopy.setOnAction(eventHandler);

        // Context menu with copy item
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem contextCopy = new MenuItem("Context Copy");
        contextCopy.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Shortcut+C"));
        contextMenu.getItems().add(contextCopy);
        contextCopy.setOnAction(eventHandler);

        Label label = new Label("Say 'Hello World'");

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(menuBar, label);
        label.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your event handler? That would greatly facilitate any answer, I think.

Comment: I have added a simple sample to my question that illustrates my issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is two instances of `EventHandlers` that react on the same key combination. You can circumvent your issue by defining the `EventHandler` once, use if for both menu types and consume the event:

```
EventHandler evtHandler = event -> {
  System.out.println("Execute copy event");
  event.consume();
};
...
editCopy.setOnAction(evtHandler);
...
contextCopy.setOnAction(evtHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks for having a go at this but I'm afraid this doesn't help :-(
(in my original code I already made use of the same handler and consumed the event).
I have changed the sample to have a single handler, but as you can see from its output, the handler is still called twice:
    ```Got event from Context Copy
    Got event from Edit Copy```

Comment: I checked with you updated code example and it works for me: I only get `Got event from Edit Copy` and only once. What JDK version are you using? I tested with 1.8.0_66.

Comment: I was using 1.8.0_72 but when I switch back to 1.8.0_66 I get the same results: still two events. I am running this on a Mac with OS X 10.10.5, what are you running it on?

Comment: I am using a Linux Mint. Though I think it is unlikely to be an issue with the OS.

Comment: Hah, I did some testing and tried the ALT modifier instead of the Shortcut modifier (CMD on a Mac, probably CTRL for you). When I do that, the event is only fired once… Still doesn't bring me closer to a solution though as I really need to have it as the Shortcut modifier…